# $R$ commutative, $I$ maximal w.r.t. non-finitely generated ideals, show $I$ not finitely generated.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, with at least one ideal which is non-finitely generated. Let $S$ be the family of such ideals. Show $S$ has a maximal element.

I need to show every chain in $S$ has an upper bound and use Zorn's lemma. I can take a chain $\mathcal{C}: I_{1} \subset I_{2} \subset I_{3} \subset \cdots$ in $S$ and let $I := \bigcup_{n} I_{n}$. If $I = (a_{1}, \ldots, a_{t})$ is finitely generated, then I want to arrive at a contradiction. From here I can say that $I_{n} = (b_{n, 1}, b_{n, 2}, \ldots) \subset (a_{1}, \ldots, a_{t})$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, whence $b_{n, i} = r_{n, 1}^{i}a_{1} + \cdots + r_{n, t}^{i}a_{t}$ (some linear combination). However, I don't know where to go from here, or if this is even the right direction. I suppose I should use the inclusion $I_{1} \subset I_{2} \subset \cdots$ somehow, seeing as subideals of finitely-generated ideals need not be finitely generated.

Comment: How do you know that there is a chain as you said, of such ideals? I mean can't there be non-finitely generated ideals such that they are not related via inclusion? For finitely generated case, we can form by adding finite elements such a chain, but for not finitely generated I don't see immediately why there is such a chain? (Just a query.)

Comment: @Rick Good point. I guess if there is no chain then it doesn't matter and Zorn still applies: every chain (though the chain has length 1) will have an upper bound trivially.

Comment: @Rick Every nonempty poset has chains... and the $\subset$ should probably not be interpreted as "strictly contains" in the text above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this looks like it might be a homework problem, I'll just give a hint.

Let's consider the extreme case where $I = (a)$, i.e., $I$ is principal.  Since $I = \bigcup_n I_n$, there must be some $k$ such that $a \in I_k$.  Then it follows (why?) that $I = I_k$, which means $I_k$ was finitely generated, contradiction.

Now suppose $I = (a_1, a_2)$.  Then there is a $k_1$ with $a_1 \in I_{k_1}$ and a $k_2$ with $a_2 \in I_{k_2}$.  See if you can use the fact that the $I_n$'s form a chain to again conclude that one of the $I_n$'s must have been finitely generated.

Once you see how to do the case where $I$ has two generators, you'll probably also see how a similar proof takes care of the general case.

Comment: Ah yes! So simple... thanks Chris (not a hw problem by the way - just practice for qualifying exams :-))

Comment: I'm glad the hint helped.  Good luck on your exams!